# How set Eastern Standard Time to Datepicker (jquery ui) - with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datapicker

How set Eastern Standard Time to Datepicker (jquery ui) - with javascript.
(I know way only with server and not client side (not looks possible for me, but maybe i wrong))

Thanks

Comment: jquery datetimepicker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)has an option of setting timezone, may be it could be useful

Answer (score 2):

you can use the jQuery Globalize plugin.

https://github.com/jquery/globalize/

Answer (score 1):

As part of the configuration, you can set it's localisation.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization

Comment: How localization will set time to Eastern Standard Time?

Comment: What country will the datepicker cater for? EST is predominately used within the US.